# Out of memory crash when trying to change image?

Tags: c#

(C#) I get an out-of-memory crash when I try setting the image of a "picture box" with one opened from a file.

My code:

```
    string file = openImageBox.Text; // Our file 
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        File.Open(file, FileMode.Open); // Open the file for use.
        Output.Text = "File Open Success!"; //Informing the user on how sucessful they are. 
        Output.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        Image img = Image.FromFile(file);
        Display.Image = img;
    }
```

Comment: It is 64x64 px. The code is under a "private void openFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}"

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the right answer (who knows.. it could be causing you all sorts of issues).

You don't need to "Open the file for use". This is holding a handle to the file you don't need. Just call `Image.FromFile` directly and it will work fine.

So remove this:

```
File.Open(file, FileMode.Open); // Open the file for use.
```

EDIT:

For completeness (and to help you learn), you need to store a reference to the stream if you want to close it. What I told you to remove above holds a handle to the file. The file is essentially open now.. until you close it.

For other code (where you're not using a method like `Image.FromFile`), you would either store a handle to the file so you can close it.. or use a `using` statement to close it for you.

Option A:

```
var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);

// do stuff here

stream.Close();
```

Option B (preferred):

```
using (var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open)) {

    // do stuff here

} // stream.Close automatically called for you
```